# jquery : toggle overlay page and color close button

Tags: jquery, scroll, colors, conflict

I created a navigation with 2 overlay page. The first for my menu and the second for a contact form.

The first problem is the switch between two color for the word "Menu".
When the visitor is on the top on the window and he clicked on "Menu" everything is ok. But when the visitor scroll down the page and clicked again on "Menu" the color of the word is the same of the background. I would like that when the visitor click on an overlay if the background is brown the "Close" button color become white and return brown only if the class smaller is active.

The second problem is the switch between the two overlays. I would like that when the visitor click on "Contact" he can close the overlay by clicking on "Close" on his right hand corner. The problem is that nothing happen :-/

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/5o2xywn1/3/)

```
$('#home-menu .toggle-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('h4.toggle-menu').text($(this).text() == 'Menu' ? 'Close' : 'Menu');

        $('#overlay-menu').toggle();

});

$('#home-menu .toggle-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('h4.toggle-menu').html($('h4.toggle-menu').html().replace('Menu','Close'));

        $('#overlay-contact').toggle();

});


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('#home-content').each(function() {
            var topDistance = $(this).offset().top;

            if ((topDistance-155) < scrollTop) {
                $('#home-menu').addClass('smaller');
            } else {
                $('#home-menu').removeClass('smaller')
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your questions correctly, I believe I've solved them with [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t6152mf/1/).

Here's your updated JavaScript code.

```
$('#home-menu .toggle-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('h4.toggle-menu').text($(this).text() == 'Menu' ? 'Close' : 'Menu');

        if ($('#overlay-contact').is(':visible')) {
            $('#overlay-contact').toggle();
            $('#toggle-menu').css("color", "");
        } else {
            $('#overlay-menu').toggle();
            if ($('#overlay-menu').is(':visible')) {
                $('.toggle-menu').css("color", "#FFFFFF");
            } else {
                $('.toggle-menu').css("color", "");
            }
        }
});

$('#home-menu .toggle-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('h4.toggle-menu').html($('h4.toggle-menu').html().replace('Menu','Close'));

        $('#overlay-contact').toggle();
        if ($('#overlay-contact').is(':visible')) {
            $('.toggle-menu').css("color", "#FFFFFF");
        } else {
            $('.toggle-menu').css("color", "");
        }
});


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('#home-content').each(function() {
            var topDistance = $(this).offset().top;

            if ((topDistance-155) < scrollTop) {
                $('#home-menu').addClass('smaller');
            } else {
                $('#home-menu').removeClass('smaller')
            }
        });

    });
```

I added some code to the `#home-menu .toggle-menu` click handler to close the contact overlay if it's open. And I added code to both handlers to set the menu/close color to be always white when an overlay is open, and be whatever color the CSS would normally make it when no overlay is open. This works because styling set in JavaScript overrides any other styling on the element. But, then erasing the styling done by the JavaScript resets it to whatever it normally would be.